# Mercurial - what's the point in distributing clones?

Tags: xcode, mercurial

The Mercurial About page says:

> "Traditional version control systems
>   such as Subversion are typical
>   client-server architectures with a
>   central server to store the revisions
>   of a project. In contrast, Mercurial
>   is truly distributed, giving each
>   developer a local copy of the entire
>   development history. This way it works
>   independent of network access or a
>   central server. Committing, branching
>   and merging are fast and cheap."

So when every developer gets a clone from ***_*** (?), then every developer can start working on the project for his own. 10 months later everyone has done something and changed RootViewController in a whole different way.

Now, what's the point of cloning the whole thing? When Dev A changes RootViewController, then Dev B wants to continue work based on that change. Or not? But how will Dev B ever get that change? By cloning the whole thing every day? How about his own changes? Is there some kind of super merge operation that merges all clones into one big superclone which everyone would have to replace with his individual clone once in a while?

I am sure Mercurial is cool and useful. But I just don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the **[basics](http://hginit.com/)** here a good introduction to Mercurial.

> You have to start some where. **hg init**
>
> All developers should have some common base / ancestor. **hg clone**
>
> They must get the changes from other developers / publish their own changes
>      **hg push** , **hg pull**, **hg bundle**
>
> You need to see what's coming into your own repo, if you pulled. **hg incoming**
>
> What changes has been made **hg diff**

Also, it is convenient to have some central repository where every one can push their changes and pull changes from.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in a distributed version control system like Mercurial, you'll still have a central repository. Either developers push into the central repo, or there is one person maintaining the central repo that pulls patches from individual developers (Linux uses this approach, for example).

If you don't use that development model, then yes, typically you'd just pull from other developers when they had completed an interesting patch.

Comment: So every developer in the team would push his changes as a patch to that central repo, and when they are all done, everyone can pull a fresh clone from that central repo again? That way, all the merging would have to be done just once on the central repo rather than every dev doing it on his own?

Comment: Sort of. Actually, the merging happens in the clone; before pushing, the developer pulls down the latest copy from the central repo, fixes any merge conflicts, and then pushes back to the central repo.

Answer (score 1):

In distributed version control system (DVCS) (mercurial and git) **no one is the master**. (Even the "server" is an arbitrary chosen master with no more right to the work of others)

Every developer can do his mess without making others work unusable. Do you remember last time some one commit something bad and none could work? This is just impossible in DVCS.

In Subversion/CVS you should branch to avoid those problems, but merge are complicated so it's done rarely/not for every tasks.

In DVCS, it' impossible not to branch, but merge are easy and should be done after all code completion (bug closed, finished feature,...). Your developers can have as many branches as he has tasks open.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from my answer to [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128131/git-or-svn-or-for-front-end-developers):

> One thing to keep in mind about DVCS is that it's not actually about the distributed-ness of it, it's about the branching and merging. DVCS makes branching and merging much easier, to the point that each developer/designer/front-ender basically has their own private branch -- their local repo. That way, they can work in parallel without stepping on each other's toes. That means they can be checking in code every few hours instead of waiting days until they have everything done to check it in.

If you're in any sort of organization (company, project team, etc.), you'll still want a central repository, so you have a canonical version of the code. Very few teams use a fully distributed workflow without a central server, because as you increase the number of people on your team, your connections increase to N<sup>2</sup>, whereas it stays N with a central server.

Comment: What exactly is a "canonical" repository? Is that different from those of the peers?

Comment: Technically, nothing. It just means that you and your team consider it to be "canonical", as in, if the code is in that repository then it's a part of your code base, and if it's not in that repo, then it's not in the code base. It's where you cut your builds from.

Answer (score 1):

If every developers clone the whole project, and then only commits locally after that, then yes, you're going to run into problems. I'd say the floppy-disk source control model is probably slightly better at that point, because you don't introduce another tool into the mix.

The thing is, that's not all that *you're supposed* to do.

Basically the workflow goes like this.

Every developer clones the local repository, and starts hacking at the code.

At some point, one of the developers have done a few commits that (s)he wants to share with the others, so that developer pushes his/her changes back to the central repository. Now the central repository has that developer's changes, but none of the other developers have them (yet.)

At their own leisure (but not too seldom, or you're going to have merge problems, like you indicate in your question), they can then pull those changes down into their own repository.

When they do this, they have branches in their repository afterwards.

First they have the latest changeset that was present in the central repository when they all cloned it, then they have two branches, one with their own changes down a linear path (usually), and one with all the changes they pulled down from the repository.

ie. they end up with something like this, (C) is the common changeset everybody cloned:

```
   o---o---o---o  <-- changes from central repository
  /
(C)
  \
   o---o---o---o  <-- their changes
```

So, now they can choose. They can continue working on their own branch, they can switch to continue working on the branch they just got from the central repository, or they can merge the two and get the best of two worlds. Typically they will choose option 3, merge.

Which leads to this:

```
   o---o---o---o
  /             \
(C)             (M)---o---o---o  <-- continued working after the merge
  \             /
   o---o---o---o
```

If they now push their changes back to the central repository, their own branch, the merge changeset, and anything they committed after the merge, is then pushed back to the central repository for others to pull.

In this way you can see that:

1. You can push and pull when you're ready for it, meaning that you can work in isolation until you're ready to share your changes with others or accept changes from others
2. You merge your own changes with others periodically

Answer (score 0):

Other people's answers are right, but I wanted to specifically answer your questions

> Now, what's the point of cloning the whole thing?

You now have your own private repository. This makes a lot of operations faster because they're local, but also allows you to make changes that are private until you want to share them.

The knock on effect of this is that developers can separate 'checking-in' with publishing their work. This means that you don't get large periods of time when nothing is checked in, because "it's not ready to go public".

> When Dev A changes RootViewController, then Dev B wants to continue work based on that change. Or not? But how will Dev B ever get that change?

**When Dev A is happy to share his changes**, he can either:

- 'push' his changes the original repo that they both cloned. Dev B can then 'pull' them from the original repo.
- 'serve' his repo, so Dev B can 'pull' directly from him.
- 'bundle' up his changes into a file, which can be sent to Dev B. He can then 'unbundle' them into his repo.
- ...probably some other methods I've forgotten.

> By cloning the whole thing every day?

Cloning is only done to create a new copy of a repository. Think "svn co".

You normally 'pull' change-sets into a repo, a bit like 'svn update'

> How about his own changes? Is there some kind of super merge operation that merges all clones into one big superclone which everyone would have to replace with his individual clone once in a while?

When change-sets are brought into a repo (e.g. via 'pull') they will exist on another branch. The repository will be said to have multiple 'heads', which are the open ends of branches. By merging these heads he'll get a single version which contains the changes from both branches. Dev B can then continue working on top of that. You would get a graph that looked something like this.

Before merge:

```
     /----o----o Head 'Dev A'
----O Central    
     \----o----o Head 'Dev B'
```

After merge:

```
     /----o----o---
----O Central      \
     \----o----o----o Head 'Dev B'
```

This merging might sound like a lot of extra work, but because Mercurial uses the information about when the developers split, and doesn't just 'diff' the two heads, it's pretty smart. In general, merge conflicts are rare.

Maybe Dev A does some more work, and then publishes to the central repo (Note: previously Dev B got Dev A's changes directly from him. Maybe B is working on a feature that relies on A's code, and needed a beta version of the code early). You could end up with a graph like this:

```
Dev A /----o----o----o----o----o----o----o--\
     /            \              \           \
----O Central      \              \           o--\        /-o
     \              \              \              \      /
Dev B \----o----o----o----o----o----o----o----o----o----o
```

Dev B has taken a couple of snapshots of Dev A's code during development, and when Dev A published his final code to the central repository, Dev B was able to pull the extra changes, merge with them, and push all of his changes back to the central repo too. Because mercurial knew about the snapshots B had of A's code, it didn't get confused when it pulled from the central repo. It just said "Oh, I've already got some of this."

So, for me the two killer features of DVCS are:

- Checking in no longer means publishing.
- Developers can share code in a controlled way, without going through the central repo and therefore publishing.

Wow, that got long, but hope it helps.